# Ascensor.js Dynamically change movement direction (queued)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascensor

I'm using [Ascensor.js](https://github.com/kirkas/Ascensor.js).

I build with this queued option:

```
var ascensor = $('#ascensor').ascensor({
    direction: [[2, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]],
    queued: "y"
});
```

After arrive to a floor, I need to chage queued to "x", to go back the same way. This is possible?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```js
ascensorInstance.options.queued = "x";`
```

I hope this help.